# One table in SQLite.net Database not returning _id for rows

Tags: c#, database, xamarin.ios, sqlite-net

I'm experiencing a weird issue with one of the tables in my database.
The problem is that this table doesn't return the id for any rows, which is causing problem when i try to delete/update rows etc.

```
ItemEntity.cs
[Table("Item")]
public class ItemEntity : IEntity
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}

ItemDatabase.cs
public class SettingDatabase : SQLiteConnection
{
    public SettingDatabase(string path) : base(path)
    {
        CreateTable<ItemEntity>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>() where T : IEntity, new()
    {            
        return (from i in Table<T>() select i).ToList();            
    }
}
```

All the other tables work fine, its just this one that does not work. Other tables have with similar/identical Get methods.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What if you rename the table? Does that help. I had a weird issue one time where I had unknowingly named a table a reserved word in SQLite. It didn't give errors but it just behaved odd.

Comment: @valdetero Thank you, It seemed like there was a problem with the "Key" property, when i renamed it it worked perfectly.